# update oracle apex collection from tabular form

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I want to know how to loop on tabular form entries and update an existing collection with new values in apex. I have created these tabular forms from collections. now I need to put all new values entered in the collection that refers to this tabular form.any help is appreciated

Comment: Basically you call apex_collection.add_member for each record. Read the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_collection.htm#AEAPI531

Comment: I think you missed what I want. I want to know how to get a tabular form row and update correspondent member in the apex collection not to add member from the form -though I don't know how to do that too- Thanks for the link I wish you understood me more and I wish you know the answer :D

Comment: If you want to update a member in a collection use apex_collection.update_member.

Comment: yes that is what I want to do. the issue here is that I want to update it with values in the tabular form. how could I get the value in plsql?

Comment: Ok, so your problem is not with updating the collection but with how to read the values from the tabular form. When the page is posted the values from the tabular form will be available in the `APEX_APPLICATION.G_Fnn` arrays. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e12510/apex_app.htm#AEAPI214

Comment: okay. so one last question, bare with me :) how could I locate the (nn) of the (F) I mean how to know the number correspondent to my form in the APEX_APPLICATION package

Comment: You can examine the id's of the generated form fields (e.g. by viewing the source of the generated page). Look for things like `id="f03_0001"` which means that column will be posted to the f03 array.

Comment: Note that f01 is special, if it's associated with a checkbox (e.g. for a record selector) the array will only contain the data for the selected records.

Comment: Thanks a million. if you wish you can put your comments as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: My pleasure. As it stands, however, the answer you've gotten from me is not relevant to your original question. If you edit your question to specify the actual problem then my answer will be appropriate. Otherwise I'll recommend closing this Q.